# How insert view action without CRUD in gii

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I doesn't use CRUD generator in gii, but want to have view action in my gridview(Read in CRUD) I have 2 models and 2 active records for tables in my database. In my controller I have action which use sqlDataProvider and inner that I use join to make dependences from my tables, because I don't know another way. 
How I can handle click from my gridview item? I want to see this item in a new view,just one of that. How can I do that? Or maybe I can make dependence from my table and use CRUD generator and it is a easier way?
Controller action:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        {
            return $this->redirect(['login']);
        }
        else
        {
        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => 'SELECT p.id,p.user_id,p.post_title,p.post_text,u.name ' .
             'FROM Posts p '.
             'INNER JOIN User u ' .
             'ON p.user_id = u.id'
]);
        return $this->render('index',['dataProvider'=>$dataProvider]);
        }
    }
```

and now when I click to item I have url like that:

http://localhost/test/basic/site/0
and I created action to hadle that url but I don't know what to do in it, now it just copy index action:

```
public function actionView($id)
   {
       if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
       {
           return $this->redirect(['login']);
       }
       else
       {
       $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
   'sql' => 'SELECT p.id,p.user_id,p.post_title,p.post_text,u.name ' .
            'FROM Posts p '.
            'INNER JOIN User u ' .
            'ON p.user_id = u.id'
]);
       return $this->render('index',['dataProvider'=>$dataProvider]);
       }
    }
```

my index view:

```
<?php
use yii\grid\GridView;
?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'ID'=>'id',
        'Title'=>'post_title',
        'Text'=>'post_text',
        'Author'=>'name',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header'=>'Действия',
            'headerOptions' => ['width' => '80'],
            'template' => '{view}',
        ],
    ],
    'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
return ['id' => $model['id']];
    },
]); ?>
```

I'm trying to do dependence(saw in another action) but don't know correct is it or now. And what is next step when I do that.

```
public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::classname(),['user_id'=>'id']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In gridview actioncolumn you should set  buttons and urlCreator

```
  <?= GridView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
      'columns' => [
          'ID'=>'id',
          'Title'=>'post_title',
          'Text'=>'post_text',
          'Author'=>'name',
          [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'header'=>'Действия',
                'headerOptions' => ['width' => '80'],
                'template' => '{view}',
                'buttons' => [
                  'scheda' => function ($url, $model) {
                      return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', $url, [
                      'title' => Yii::t('app', 'My  View Title'),
                      ]);
                  }
               ],
              'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                  if ($action === 'view') {
                      $url = Url::to(['/my-controller-name/view', 'id' =>$model->id]);
                  return $url;
                  }
              }           

          ],
      ],

      ]); 
  ?>
```